# Subtract amount automaticaly from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery, how to auto subtracting amount from input after typing it without button
Ex. When I type a number in an input , I want to subtract it -5 after I leave it automaticaly without submit button , 200 will be 195 .
Is it posible?

Comment: Yes that's possible.

Comment: use on change https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: @justDan's comment + try at least once

Comment: You're fairly new, so folks should go kind of easy on you. What have you tried? Have you run into a wall as far as your coding goes? That's what we're here for. General questions will get down voted...

Comment: @Snowmonkey I don't know is it posible to do it in jquery or not :(

Comment: Have a look here, the sooner you grasp the idea of how to ask on SO the better. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's a quick way to do this in jquery. Try the code below. Add a number and tab off the input or click out of it and the value will change.

```js
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  var num = $(this).val() - 5;
  $(this).val(num);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: In case you are looking for a pure JavaScript alternative (without jQuery):**

You can attach this process to an input event such as `onkeyup` or `onfocusout`:

```js
function update() {
  amount = document.getElementById("amount");
  amount.value = parseInt(amount.value) - 5;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="amount" onfocusout="update()">
```

Comment: The OP is actually asking for jQuery solution if I am not missing something.

Comment: Ops, my mistake!! Well, as someone already posted a corrected answer using jQuery I will edit the answer as a pure JavaScript alternative. Thanks for pointing out!!

Answer (score 0):

JavaSript solution.
This will work for you.

```
document.getElementById("input").onblur = substract;

function substract() {
  let firstValue = event.currentTarget.value;
  let finalValue = Number(firstValue) - 5;
  document.getElementById("input").value = finalValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need need to create a function and attach the input Element to the function.

Creating a function to reduce input element on change by 5.

```
var myfunction = function(){
      var value = parseInt(this.value);
     //check if input is of type int and less than five to avoid negative numbers.
     if( !value || value < 5 ){
          return false;
      }
     this.value = value - 5;
 };

 //ataching function to the element
var element = document.getElementById('my_input');
element.addEventListener( 'change', myfunction, false );
```